# Angular Tratamento de JSON

Tags: typescript, angular-6

Gostaria de saber se é necessário fazer o tratamento do JSON para utilizar o 
two-way databinding no HTML. Consegui fazer a leitura dele sem o tratamento, porem não sei se esta é a forma correta.

Segue o código:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.emissor = 'Luis Henrique';
  this._http.get<PreparacaoDeMensagem[]>("../assets/db/mensagem.json")
    .subscribe(mensagem => {
      this.mensagem = mensagem        
      for (let i=0;i < mensagem.length;i++){
        this.adicionarMensagem(this.mensagem[i]);
      }
  )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa de nenhum tratamento.

Objetos javascript sāo tratados como objetos e o retorno json da chamada de seu serviço http é automaticamente tranformado em um objeto javascript nativo e pronto para uso.

Espero ter ajudado.